# How do I cite CVPR workshop conference "short" paper?

Tags: publications, citations, conference, computer-science, workshop

CVPR doesn't add workshop "short papers" into the proceedings, but they have uploaded all of it onto a github.io repo.

How do I cite this when it's not in proceedings?

Comment: Many CVPR workshops do have proceedings, for example see https://openaccess.thecvf.com/CVPR2020_workshops/menu , there is even a bibtex file for citation for each paper.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Those are all the long papers. The short papers do not show up there

Answer (score 1):

**Clearly.**

The main purpose of a bibliography entry is to properly identify the work, with enough information that (at least in principle) your readers can find the work and read it for themselves.  If the github.io repository doesn't suggest a citation format, make up something reasonable that serves that purpose.  The precise formatting doesn't matter (or if it does, the editor will fix it for you).  For example:

> [10] J. Smith and R. Tyler.  BADWOLF: A temporally agnostic relational
> database information system.  Presented at the 13th Gallifreyan
> Workshop on Untempered Schismatics, Arcadia, December 2020.
> https://torchwood.github.io/badworf.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If your paper is already into Google Scholar, it id easy, anyway, eventually, it will (if not yet). You can cite like the following example:

> Robertson, Eric, et al. "Manipulation Data Collection and Annotation Tool for Media Forensics." *Proceedings of the IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition Workshops*. 2019.

Additionally, you can provide a download/view link along with it. The above citation will work for both short and long paper. So, the template is:

> Author, F., Author, S., Author T., "Paper Title." *Proceedings of the Conference Name Here Workshop*. 20YY. [Link]

Comment: Are you sure? CVPR doesn't have proceedings for workshop papers

Comment: Oh sorry, I just remembered and misspoke. Mine is a short paper, not a long paper. hence it doesn't go into the proceedings. How would I cite it?

Comment: The same way you would cite any paper; short or long, it's a paper. The answer given above works for both short and long paper.

Comment: I am not sure that this is correct. "Proceedings of the IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition Workshops" is a specific volume that contains only a subset of the workshop papers that went into the official proceedings. So wouldn't it be wrong to cite as if this paper was in it too, when it wasn't?